# Actility: What does the appKeyEncryptionMode mean?

Tags: lorawan

After registering a device in Actility, we have recently seen the following keys in the API response from Actility/Thingpark:

```
  { 
  "appKey":"C2E8A28EC0062EF2C276094A0FACC87F",
  "appKeyEncryptionMode":"LRC_CLUSTER_KEY",
   }
```

The [Actility API documentation](https://partners.thingpark.com/en/node/228) explains the appKey, but not the appKeyEncryptionMode. Does anyone know what it means? What does it tell us?

In fact, we have seen that after registering a device with the Thingpark APIs, we observe that the appkey (seen in a response as above) differs from the one we supplied during device registration. A potential appkey encrytion would explain this kind of behavior, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the key is encrypted, the lrcClusterKeyVersion defines the encryption schema.
So yes, you are right. If you see a different key and it means it is encrypted.